# Can I groud 12v Negative and 5v Negativ at the same time?

Tags: arduino

I have an external 12v power supply with arduino mega, I want to control a 12v led strip from ardunio mega, so I'm confused little bit can I connect arduino ground to 12v ground? Is this connection damage my ardunio ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should really do a little bit more research before asking a question. There must be 100's of thousands of pages of information on how to correctly ground circuits.

That said, the simple answer is yes. In fact most arduino tutorials recommend connecting the ground from your arduino to the ground of the external components. Using a separate ground connection for the LED strip and your arduino may cause ground loops which are a completely different problem.

Edit: After adding your circuit you need to be aware that even though the LED strip may have a positive and negative side this doesn't mean +12 and -12. It is referring to the positive and negative sides of the circuit, in this case Vcc and GND.

This isn't true for your power supply however. Power supplies can supply positive and negative voltages. If your power supply is a dual rail power supply then **do not** connect the -12V to the ground, the potential difference will cause you to have +24V on your LED strip, not to mention all sorts of other problems

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Can you give circuit diagram it can be help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No I can't, there are tons of resources out there for you. If you edit your question to show what circuit diagram you have already then I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes I have added the circuit can you guid me.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

You have drawn the power supply with +12V and -12V, is this what it says on the power supply? What power supply are you using, are you sure it isn't +12 and GND?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect the only ground between Arduino and power supply.
Often, I adding a ferrit bead between them to reduce noise from power supply unit( type as switching). In some case to communication between 2 board using differrent voltage, you must connect ground together to synchronus the volatge.
You must remember cant connect the power line toghether.